# Making own Hammock

Tags: knots, diy, hammock

I have been looking but unable to find a good video or step by step with photos to make my own Hammock. I have a ton of paracord lying around and plan on using that, but I'd really like a guide and/or to learn from someone else's mistakes before I start.

Comment: Are you looking to weave your own hammock entirely from paracord? Or use fabric and simply create the ropework?

Comment: Entirely weave. Nothing but paracord and probably two rings to use as anchors.

Comment: i guess this question belongs to DIY forum. http://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You must have seen this video of an emergency hammock: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P9dka82KdrM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will likely want to check out http://www.hammockforums.net/  They have a DIY section has tutorials on all sorts of hammock building or hammock accessories.